# How to avoid deployment of all five functions in a server of serverless framework if only one function is changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-codepipeline

I have a [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) service with (say)five aws lambda functions using python. By using **github** I have created a [CodePipeline](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwiV4tWqpdbbAhUDHisKHRvvCvAYABAAGgJzZg&sig=AOD64_1wGsvfJl_3vtTrnFem0iSJSddtJg&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjojtCqpdbbAhUPWX0KHc0pCiIQ0QwIJg&adurl=) for CI/CD.

When I push the code changes, it deploys all the functions even  only function is changed.

I want to avoid the deployment of all functions and the CI/CD should determine the changed function and deploy it. Rest of functions should not be deployed again.

Moreover, is there anyway to deal with such problems using AWS SAM, as at this stage I have an option to switch towards SAM by quitting *serverless framework*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "native" way to do it. You would need to write a bash that will loop through the changed files and call `sls deploy -s production -f` for each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced this issue, and eventually it drove me to create an alternative.

[Rocketsam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rocketsam) takes advantage of sam local to allow deploying only changed functions instead of the entire microservice.
It also supports other cool features such as:

- Fetching live logs for each function
- Sharing code between functions
- Template per function instead of one big template file

Hope it solves your issue :)